# How to test if all the levels have the same success/fail probability?

Tags: binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I have a csv data set like this.

```
Levels, Trial, Fail
1,100,1
2,200,3
3,300,4
```

How do I test if the probability of fail or success is the same across all the levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do Fisher's Exact test on a 3 X 2 contingency table.  The null hypothesis is that all 3 levels have the same proportions of success/fail.